# Constraint optimization problem - Solution verification

Tags: optimization, constraints

I have the function $$ f(x,y) = 0.5(0.7x-0.3y)^2 + \frac{1}{3}(0.7y-0.3x)^2$$

Constraint : $$g(x,y) = 2+0.6x-y$$

Parametrization of $$g(x,y) => h(x) = (h_1(x),h_2(x))^T = (x , 2+0.6x)^T$$

The solution for the gradient is as follows:

$$\nabla (x,h_2(x)) = (0.34x-0.7, -0.1x + 0.833...)^T$$

Tangent vector is given by: $$ t = (h_1(x)',h_2(x)')^T = (1,0.6)^T$$

At $$ x = x^*, y = h_2(x^*) = y^* $$

Scalar product should be zero:

$$ t \cdot \nabla (x^*,y^*) = 0.28x^* -0.2 = 0$$

However my calculations give me $$ -0.26x^* -0.2 = 0$$

Is the handout solution wrong or where is my mistake?

Comment: Huh? You say $g(x,y) = 2 + 0.6x - y$. For given values of $x, y$, $g(x,y)$ is a real number. But then you have this parametrization where $g(x,y) = (x, 2 + 0.6x)^T$, which is not a real number. Which is it?

Comment: Im struggling with this topic. Since the parametrization is used to calculate the tangent vector I wrote the parametrization above so people can verify it is correct..I'm not fully undestanding what I'm doing tbh...the solution explicitly states the tangent being the derivatives of h1(x), h2(x), also we use x = h1(x), y = h2(x) as points (plural) where the gradient fullfills constraint...

Comment: Well, writing that $g(x,y)$, a real-valued function, is equal to $h(x)$, a vector-valued function, is not going to help with your understanding, nor your ability to communicate with others. If you have still not broken the very bad habit of novice algebra students of putting "=" everywhere even though you do not mean the two sides to actually be equal, then it is well past time for you to stop saying things you do not mean.

Comment: Your right I could have made it clearer...I meant the parametrization of g(x,y) as h(x)